# Finding the minimum distance between 2 graphs

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have 2 graphs $y = x$ and $y = x^2 + 1$. I need to find the minimum distance between the 2 of them.

I've determined the parametric equations for them:

$r(s) = (s, s)$

and

$r(t) = (t, t^2 + 1)$

I've determined the distance formula to be:

$d = \sqrt{(t-s)^2 +(t^2+1-s)^2}$

However, from this point I'm stuck. I know I need to do some form of partial differentiation.
I don't know what I need to do with partial derivatives with respect to s and t for me to determine the distance.

Comment: You can also do it without partial differentiation- find a common normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use calculus instead of geometry, you would be much better off minimising the square of the distance. The partial derivatives are then pretty straight-forward. A point suspected of being a minimum will be a point where both partial derivatives are equal to zero. One partial derivative of $d^2$ is $$-2 (-s + t) - 2 (1 - s + t^2)$$ and the other is $$2 (-s + t) + 4 t (1 - s + t^2)$$ You can now find a point where both are equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Do you potentially have any recommendations on good resources for learning material?

Comment: What do you want to learn?

Comment: Multivariable calculus

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving the line $y = x$ towards the parabola. At some point, the line and the parabola will touch at exactly one point, and the line will be tangent to the parabola.

Therefore you have to solve $f'(x) = 2x = 1$. Find the point on the parabola that satisfies this, and then find the shortest distance to the line: the perpendicular distance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am however required to solve the problem making use of the distance formula.

Comment: @DamianJacobs, I found (3/5, 3/8) on $y=x$ and (1/2, 5/4) on  $y=x^2+1$ which gives $d=\sqrt {50}/8=0.88..$ . is this correct?

Comment: how did you get 2 different values for y and x on y = x? I got (7/8, 7/8) and then my second point was the same as yours

Comment: $d = (3\sqrt{2})/8 = 0.53$
Here are the 2 graphs drawn out:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fzeiaom1bz